# как работать с первыми элементами с определенным атрибутом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как работать с первыми 4мя элементами, у которых есть определенный атрибут ?
Нужно работать с элементами, со style='display: none'
структура html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//получаем все элементы со значением атрибута style 'display: none;'
var elements = jQuery('[style = "display: none;"]');

//выбираем первые четыре элемента
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(elements[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 1</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 2</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 3</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 4</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 5</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 6</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 7</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elements = $(".wrapper div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
}).slice(0,4);

elements.css("display","block").html("hello")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
    <div style="display: none;">item</div>
</div>
```